# Dom of $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus

**Short question:** Let $\overline{\mathbb{R}}=\mathbb{R}\bigcup\{\pm\infty\}$ andconsider a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\overline{\mathbb{R}}$. I found the definition of $dom(f)$ to be
$$dom(f) := \{ x\in\mathbb{R}^n|\,|f(x)|<\infty\}.$$

In case of a function with image in $\mathbb{R}$, **NOT** in $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$, this implies
$$dom(f) = \mathbb{R}^n$$
Right?

Comment: $dom(f)= \mathbb R^n$ not $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Sorry, typo.. But this is always true, right?

Comment: Yes, this is a tautology. If $f(x) \in \mathbb R$ for all $x \in \mathbb R^n$ then $dom(f)=\mathbb R^n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some definitions of the word *function* require that the domain is the entire set on the left hand side of the arrow, and then the condition $|f(x)|<\infty$ is a tautology.

Other definitions call such a thing a *mapping* or a *total function* and then the expression $f(x)$ need not be defined for all $x\in\mathbb R^n.$

But in either case you are right that the condition $|f(x)|<\infty$ makes no sense unless $f(x)$ is defined as a vector in the first place, so it can only be a tautology.

Comment: No,  $f(x)$ is in the codomain, so it makes sense to talk about $|f(x)|<\infty$ with it being a scalar quantity.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an illustrative example,  consider $f:\mathbb R ^2 \to \overline {\mathbb R}$ given by $f(x,y)=\frac 1 {x^2 +y^2}$
Using limits, we can sensibly define $f(0,0)=\infty$.

In which case,  the normal domain of this function would be $\mathbb R ^2$, but the $dom(f)$ in your definition would be $\mathbb R^2 -\{(0,0)\}$